# tcpdump to capture socket data

Tags: sockets, tcpdump, packet-sniffers

Can use tcpdump to capture socket data ?. Since , at the listener end i'm freqyently getting some additional info along with send message.

In between client and end listener , one edge server and one application server is running, not sure at which point that additional info is being added. To troubleshoot, I tried to use tcpdump to capture the socket data. But I couln't capture it.

Can someone please tell me, tcpdump is not fit to capture socket data?. if so, then which one is correct one to do this.

Note: I'm Using CentOS

Comment: What do you call "socket data" / "additional info along with send message" ? tcpdump capture _everything_, the whole packet as seen "on the wire" (well, by default, the first 65535 bytes of a packet actually, but that can be setup using the `-s` / `--snapshot-length` option). What "additional info along with send message" are you missing?

Answer (score -1):

tcpdump can capture data base on port as following:
  tcpdump tcp port 23 and host 210.27.48.1 -w temp.pcap

If you still can't capture any data, you can capture data for the interface to ensure your tcpdump is working:
  tcpdump -i eth1 -w temp.pcap

ps: If your client and your server are on the same machine, you need to capture the lo interface.